# Passing the data in the tables from database to modal

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to pass the data in the table to a modal textbox through a clickable row. The data's are already displayed in the table. When row is clicked, it displays the modal but the textboxes are blank. The data's in the table was from the database.

This is the codes:

Php:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width= device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "bs/css/bootstrap.css">

    <script src = "bs/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "bs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>  
<body>        
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <?php include("header.php"); ?>
        </div>
        <div class = "navigation">
            <?php include("navigator.php"); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <center>          
    <style>
        table tr:not(:first-child){
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        table tr:not(:first-child)hover{
            background-color:azure;
            color:black;

        }
    </style> 

    <?php
        include("dbConfig.php");

        $result = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT * FROM information");
        echo "<table id=table border = 1 width = 50%>
            <tr>
            <th align = center> Control # </th>
            <th> Last Name </th>
            <th> First Name </th>
            <th> Contact Number </th>
            </tr>"; 
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<form action = method =post>";
            echo "<tr data-toggle=modal data-target=#fmodal name = pass type = submit>";
            echo "<td id='cn'>".$row['Control_Number']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Last_Name']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['First_Name']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Contact_Number']. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM information WHERE Control_Number=$_POST[cn]");
            while($rowval = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                $controlnumber= $rowval['Control_Number'];
                $lastname= $rowval['Last_Name'];
                $firstname= $rowval['First_Name'];
                $contactnumber= $rowval['Contact_Number'];
            }
        }
    ?>

    <div class = "modal fade" id = "fmodal" role = "dialog">
        <div class = "modal-dialog" role = "document">
            <div class = "modal-content">
                <div class = "modal-header">
                    <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss = "modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4>FORM</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-body text-center">
                    <label>Control Number:</label>
                    <input class = "input-lg" type = "text" id = "Control_Number" value = '<?php echo $controlnumber; ?>'><br>
                    <label>Last Name:</label>
                    <input class = "input-lg" type = "text" id = "Last_Name" value = '<?php echo $lastname; ?>'><br>
                    <label>First Name:</label>
                    <input class = "input-lg" type = "text" id = "First_Name" value = '<?php echo $firstname; ?>'><br>
                    <label>Contact Number:</label>
                    <input class = "input-lg" type = "text" id = "Contact_Number" value = '<?php echo $contactnumber; ?>'><br>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: First of all, take a look at http://bobby-tables.com since your application runs at a really high risk of SQL injection. Use prepared statements for your query, never put user inputs directly in your query! For your problem: Define the variables outside of the loop first like `$controlnumber = "";` - look for `PHP while loop scope` if you want more informations about scope of variables in PHP.

Comment: @MYxx  as i understood your question there are row of table data when clicked on submit button modal must pop up and the values of particular must be displayed in table. but or this you need to us `AJAX` .

Comment: @MYxx here is the similar example with `php ` `mysql ` `ajax ` `jquery ` . click on this links and tell me whether is this you are looking for or need i need to add more ..  [link 1](https://ibb.co/n4N0fF)  [link 2](https://ibb.co/kXYj7v)

Comment: @PavanBaddi the link 1

Answer (score 0):

@MYxx here is what you wanted. Here i have used `OOPS PHP`  `MYSQLi Prepare` `JQuery Ajax` and `JSON` to send and received data and display in modal.

Why `MYSQLi PREPARED STATEMENTS` because it prevents `SQL INJECTION` for more info click on this link [sql injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

*If you are new to PHP and MySQL then don't worry, you will get adjusted to this soon.  If you are having problems understanding this answer, I will be happy to help you*.

index.php

```
    <?php
    include('Table_info.php');

    $tbl_data = new Table_info();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th> First Name </th>
                <th> Last Name </th>
                <th> Contact Number </th>
                <th> Control Number </th>
                <th> Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $tbl_data->show_table();

            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- ADDED THE MUSIC MODAL-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal fade" id="fmodal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">User data</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="userdata_div">
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="">
                        <p>Firstname</p>
                        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>Lastname</p>
                        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>Contact_Number</p>
                        <input type="text" name="Contact_Number" id="Contact_Number">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>Lastname</p>
                        <input type="text" name="Control_Number" id="Control_Number">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group text-center" style="margin:0;">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" class="btn btn-default" style="border:1px solid #451;">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    getdata();
});

function getdata(){
    $('.open_model_btn').click(function(){
        $('#fmodal').modal();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        //alert('works');

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'Table_info.php',
            data:{slno_id:id},
            success:function(data){
                var res = JSON.parse(data);

                for(var i in res){
                    $('#id').val(res[i].id);
                    $('#fname').val(res[i].First_Name);
                    $('#lname').val(res[i].Last_Name);
                    $('#Contact_Number').val(res[i].Contact_Number);
                    $('#Control_Number').val(res[i].Control_Number);
                }
            }
        });

        $('#id, #fname, #lname, #Contact_Number, #Control_Number').val('');
    });
}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

PHP Class file name: Table_info.php

```
    <?php
    class Table_info{
        private $link;

        function __construct(){
            $this->link = new mysqli('localhost','root','','example');

            if($this->link->connect_error){
                die ('connection failed'.$this->link->connect_error);
            }
        }

        function show_table(){
            $sql = $this->link->stmt_init();
            $i=1;
            if($sql->prepare("SELECT id,First_Name,Last_Name,Contact_Number,Control_Number FROM information")){
                $sql->bind_result($id,$First_Name,$Last_Name,$Contact_Number,$Control_Number);

                $sql->execute();

                $sql->store_result();

                if($sql->num_rows > 0){
                    while($sql->fetch()){
            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $i;?></td>   
                            <td><?php echo $First_Name;?></td>  
                            <td><?php echo $Last_Name;?></td>   
                            <td><?php echo $Contact_Number;?></td>  
                            <td><?php echo $Control_Number;?></td>  
                            <td><button class="btn btn-success open_model_btn" id="<?php echo $id;?>">Show</button></td>    
                        </tr>
            <?php
                        $i++;
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Error'.$this->link->error;
            }
        }

        function get_data_modal($slnoid){
            $sql = $this->link->stmt_init();
            $i=1;
            if($sql->prepare("SELECT id,First_Name,Last_Name,Contact_Number,Control_Number FROM information WHERE id=?")){
            $sql->bind_param('i',$slnoid);
                $sql->bind_result($id,$First_Name,$Last_Name,$Contact_Number,$Control_Number);

                $sql->execute();

                $sql->store_result();

                if($sql->num_rows > 0){
                    while($sql->fetch()){
                        $arr[] = array(
                            'id'=>$id,
                            'First_Name'=>$First_Name,
                            'Last_Name'=>$Last_Name,
                            'Contact_Number'=>$Contact_Number,
                            'Control_Number'=>$Control_Number,
                            'report'=>'Success'
                        );
                    }

                    echo json_encode($arr);
                }
                else
                {
                    $arr = array(
                            'statuss'=>false,
                            'report'=>'No data available'
                        );

                    echo json_encode($arr);
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                $err = 'Error'.$this->link->error;

                $arr = array(
                        'statuss'=>false,
                        'report'=>$err
                    );

                echo json_encode($arr);
            }
        }
    }

    $tbl_data = new Table_info();

    if(isset($_POST['slno_id'])){
        $slnoid = $_POST['slno_id'];

        $tbl_data->get_data_modal($slnoid);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Good grief.  No need to scream.  I'm editing that out.

Comment: @cale_b its ok ill remove it